# Bug of log4j when log empty Map

Tags: log4j2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Java Codes:

```
    Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    System.out.println(logger);
    logger.info("{}-{}", System.currentTimeMillis(), map);
```

Output:

```
org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger@1c2c22f3
20:12:56.257 [main] INFO com.xxx - 1639051976254-1639051976254
```

Obviously, the correct output should be `1639051976254-{}`
Does any body have the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a known bug: [LOG4J2-2623](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2623). Your message is formatted twice:

- the first time by Log4j 2.x,
- the second time by whatever SLF4J backend you are using (probably Logback).

Comment: OK, Thanks a lot